# X-editable and DataTables Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables, x-editable

I made a Jsfiddle of my issue but it doesn't reflect the problem i have properly so i will explain.

I have 10 column table using datatables Version 1.10 with bootstrap3,
X-editable with inline edit and onblur:'ignore'(for multiple edits)

### X | Y Headers

a | b Cell values

So if i click on both a & b cells something like this will happen

### X | Y

a(inline edit mode)
b(inline edit mode)

the cell b gets to the bottom of cell a in X column when clicked.

I Solved this issue by using  tags inside  Tags.
But then some of my datatable filters were not working,
And if i remove span tags from all columns, Filters will work fine.

Here is the Jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/4346/

```
 $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
$('#users a').editable({
    type: 'text',
    name: 'username',
    url: '/post',
    title: 'Enter username'
});
$('.s').editable({
    type: 'text',
    name: 'username',
    url: '/post',
    title: 'Enter username'
});
//ajax emulation
$.mockjax({
    url: '/post',
    responseTime: 200
});
```

Actually i didn't know how to edit onblur option in code so it won't reflect my problem correctly.

UPDATE : Following is the generated HTML

Code for the select in datatables

```
   var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    $("#example thead td ").each( function ( i ) {

        if(i>1)
         select = $('<select class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>')
            .appendTo( $(this).empty() )
            .on( 'change', function () {
                table.column( i )
                    .search( $(this).val() )
                    .draw();
            }
                 );


        table.column( i ).data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
        if(i>1)
            select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )

        } );
    } );
```

This is my issue 
So for column with number it works even when there is span tag in the value.

```
<option value=""></option><option value="<span>0</span>">0</option><option value="<span>10</span>">10</option><option value="<span>1</span>">1</option><option value="<span>2</span>">2</option><option value="<span>3</span>">3</option><option value="<span>4</span>">4</option><option value="<span>5</span>">5</option><option value="<span>8</span>">8</option>
```

But for columns with text in them it doesn't match.

```
<select class="form-control"><option value=""></option><option value="<span></span>"></option><option value="<span>TEAM1</span>">TEAM1</option><option value="<span>TEAM2</span>">TEAM2</option><option value="<span>TEAM3</span>">TEAM3</option><option value="<span>TEAM4</span>">TEAM4</option><option value="<span>UNASSIGNED</span>">UNASSIGNED</option></select>
```

So can anyone please tell me how can i remove the span tag in the value.

Update I am close to the answer i know,

I just have to change the `d` obj in the main jquery.datatables.js such as to select data inside `span` tag rather than `td`.

Comment: One more thing which i just found out, I am using Select filters but if i use text filters all the column filters are working fine.

Comment: But if there is a problem in my data then filters shouldn't have worked even when i remove span tags. but they work perfectly when i remove span tags.